# Shopping cart with Redis & Devise Guest user (Rails 4) - How to move guest_user cart to registered user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, redis, shopping-cart

I'm building a shopping cart with redis, following this tutorial : http://www.sitepoint.com/build-online-store-rails/

I'm using guest_user with devise, and move the data of the guest user to the newly created user, through the method "move_to(@user)", which works fine.

In my overriden registrations_controller.rb :

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    current_user.move_to(@user) if current_user && current_user.guest?
    sign_up("user", @user)
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

In my model user.rb :

```
def move_to(user)
  order_products.update_all(user_id: user.id) 
  user.shipping_name = shipping_name
end
```

I can't figure out which Redis command I should add inside my move_to(user) method, in order to "transfert" the shopping-cart to the newly created user.

Here is my redis commands in my user model :

```
#to show the number of items in cart

def cart_count
  $redis.scard "cart#{id}"
end

#to calculate the total of the shopping cart

def cart_total_price
  total_price = 0
  get_cart_order_products.each { |order_product| total_price+= order_product.total_price }
  total_price
end

#to get each of the order_products added to the shopping cart

def get_cart_order_products
  cart_ids = $redis.smembers "cart#{id}"
  OrderProduct.find(cart_ids)
end
```

Any idea which syntax I should use in order to get the gest_user cart to the newly created user?

Many thanks in advance!